# Having a hard time understanding generators

Tags: python

I would like to create a function, which acts as a generator and yields the prefixes of a list each time. Example:

```
a = iter([1,2,3,4])
print(next(prefixes(a)))
print(next(prefixes(a)))
print(next(prefixes(a)))
```

should return

```
[[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

My function so far was looking like:

```
def prefixes(li):

    cur = []
    for element in li:
        cur.append(element)
        cur = copy.deepcopy(cur)
        yield cur
```

I played around with copy, because I always get just one single appended item. How can I fix this, such that the input creates exactly that output? More importantly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, you can use `itertools.accumulate`: `prefixes = accumulate([1,2,3,4], lambda acc, x: acc + [x], initial=[])`. (Note that this would still return the list itself as a prefix; with an arbitrary iterator, there's no way to tell you've reached the end of the sequence before you try to generate the next prefix.)

Comment: I'd advise to do `yield copy.deepcopy(cur)` instead. Otherwise the recipient of the yielded list can modify it and thus modify the list your generator is working with.

Comment: @chepner That's also [affected by consumer modifications](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsIwEETv@Yo9NhgErQcp9EtCD7EmuJBkw3YL8etjSxWcywzvwZS3vCj398KtBaYEKJ6FKC6AqRALuHle0xqdeKUK@4DVLzD@4c5ezNX05jYZiC49nm6XBuqwN5zA1s1gRkEXRztppQIxHF8bh9/roGBLYczSHUx/yb7Pc/SOO93aBw), though.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have just realized this, but I am not really sure what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Given that a deep copy could be rather expensive, I'd leave it up to the consumer to decide if they need their own copy, and let it be on their head if modifying the list modifies the subsequent prefixes.

Comment: @chepner Ok. Then maybe also do `lambda acc, x: acc.append(x) or acc` for even more speed, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy Am I correct with the assumption that `yield copy.deepcopy(cur)` actually assings an unique list do the recipient of that list, while not using `yield copy.deepcopy(cur)` changes the list hold by the generator?

Comment: Yielding a copy means the recipient can do with it whatever they want, won't affect what the generator has. Not yielding a copy makes the generator "vulnerable" to modifications by the recipient (like the `.clear()` in my demo).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating different generators on your way (with `prefixes(...)`). You only need to create one and show it to `next`:

```py
import copy

def prefixes(lst):
    cur = []
    yield cur
    for element in lst:
        cur.append(element)
        yield copy.deepcopy(cur)

ps = prefixes([1,2,3,4])
print(next(ps)) # []
print(next(ps)) # [1]
print(next(ps)) # [1, 2]
print(next(ps)) # [1, 2, 3]
```

And just for fun, a recursive approach (although I am not sure if it is any better):

```py
def prefixes(lst, head=None):
    if not lst: # if empty list
        return
    if head is None:
        yield (head := [])
    yield (head := [*head, lst[0]])
    yield from prefixes(lst[1:], head)

print(*prefixes([1,2,3,4])) # [] [1] [1, 2] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `prefixes()` returns a new generator, and thus, a completely new `cur`. So, each time, it fills the empty list one element taken from the given iterable.

In order to keep taking things from the same generator, you need to call it once, save that to a variable, and then call `next()` on the variable.

```
def prefixes(li):
    cur = []
    yield cur  # you say you want the empty list as the first returned value, this is how
    for element in li:
        cur.append(element)
        cur = copy.deepcopy(cur)
        yield cur 

gen = prefixes(iter([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(next(gen))  # []
print(next(gen))  # [1]
print(next(gen))  # [1, 2]
```

Comment: I see, but although it returns a new generator each time, the returned elements of the list increment, so each generator call does not use a fresh input? Also, the copy would be not necessary anymore, I guess?

Comment: Well, no, each successive call would use the same `a`, which has already had elements taken from it. The copy _is_ necessary if you're assigning the returned values to anything, because you wouldn't want all the returned values to always be the same as each other at any point in time.

Answer (score 1):

A generator function returns a generator object; when you call next on the generator object the body of the function is executed up to the next `yield` (or until an explicit or implicit return) and the yielded value is returned by the `next` call while the generator object's state is updated so that the next time you call `next` on it the execution resumes where it left off (including any changes to locals). What you should be doing is:

```
a = iter([1,2,3,4])
gen = prefixes(a)
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

This prints

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

What you were doing is create a fresh generator object with every call to `prefixes`, each of which then starts its iteration from the beginning (as they're completely independent of each other).

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, but you create with each `next(prefixes(a))` call a new generator instance and print only the first yielded element.

You need to create only one instance and call `next` on this one multiple times. Furthermore you don't need the `iter()` around your `list`.

```py
import copy

def prefixes(li):
    cur = []
    for element in li:
        cur.append(element)
        cur = copy.deepcopy(cur)
        yield cur


a = [1,2,3,4]
generator = prefixes(a)
print(next(generator))
# [1]
print(next(generator))
# [1, 2]
print(next(generator))
# [1, 2, 3]
print(next(generator))
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using copy you could slice the list.
Slice operator will return a shallow copy.
Assuming you have simple values or don't need deep copy the following will work:

```
def prefixes(li):
    for i in range(len(li) + 1):
        yield li[:i]
```

It can be further simplified to a single generator expression:

```
def prefixes(li):
    return (li[:i] for i in range(len(li) + 1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need the copy/deepcopy. As others mentioned, you need only call `prefixes()` once, to return the iterator, and then call `next()` multiple times to walk through the results.

Here's an example, using a for loop instead of calling `next()`:

```
def prefixes(i):
   p = []
   for x in i:
     yield p
     p.append(x)

for prefix in prefixes(iter([1,2,3,4])):
   print(prefix)
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```